# What is the risk of transferring your funds to the Matic mainnet?

Tags: polygon, layer-2

Fees on the Matic are so much lower compared to Ethereum mainnet, but what is the risk of this? There should be some price I pay (or risk I take) when holding my funds on Matic, otherwise everyone would use it instead of Ethereum mainnet?
So what is the risk am I taking when using Matic compared to Ethereum mainnet (can my funds be double-spent, stolen or something else?)? I think it is a basic question, but I **really** cannot find anything regarding this topic.